# How to allow subclasses to use parent class's nib

Tags: ios, xib, nib

Say I have a parent view class, that contains at least 1 property:

```
  class BaseView : UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
  }
```

This class has a corresponding xib file with an outlet connection made from the xib to the myLabel property.

Now let's say we also have some child classes that inherit from this class:

```
  class ChildView : BaseView {
     func setup() {}
  }
```

ChildView has some custom logic but can reuse all of the views from BaseView. It doesn't (or I'd prefer to avoid it having) its own corresponding xib file.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
  let childView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: BaseView.self), owner: nil, options:nil)?.first as! ChildViewA
```

but this doesn't work. Neither does:

```
  let childView = ChildView()
  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: BaseView.self owner: childView, options: nil)
```

Is there anyway to allow a child view to inherit from its parent view's xib file in a similar way?

Comment: You want use the same xib file with two classes ?

Comment: Yes, although only with the relationship the second class is inheriting from the first.

Comment: There is no concept of inheriting in xib files. You can use the inherited classes but not the xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the root view in the nib is of type `BaseView`, so `as! ChildViewA` fails. Since you don't have access to the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` that the nib loader uses to unarchive the xib, there is no easy way to substitute your own class during unarchiving.

Here's a workaround.

Do **not** embed the `BaseView` itself in the xib. Instead, make the top-level view in the xib be a plain `UIView`, and set the File's Owner custom class to `BaseView`. Then delete all of the connections to the top-level view and set them on the File's Owner instead. Also give `BaseView` a `rootViewFromNib` outlet, and connect it to the root view.

Then, give `BaseView` an initializer that loads its nib and adds that `rootViewFromNib` to itself as a subview, with its frame pinned to the `BaseView`'s own `bounds`. You can use autoresizing to do it.

In the end, `BaseView` should look like this:

```
class BaseView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
    // other outlets, etc.

    @IBOutlet private var rootViewFromNib: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        Bundle(for: BaseView.self).loadNibNamed("BaseView", owner: self, options: nil)
        rootViewFromNib.frame = bounds
        rootViewFromNib.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        rootViewFromNib.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(rootViewFromNib)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

and `BaseView.xib` should look like this:

[image: BaseView.xib]